# How to create the magento2 Mega drop down menu?

Tags: magento2, category-tree, topmenu

Creating mega **drop down menu** on magento2, able to get the data from the database **product categories** and **subcategories**

Answer (score 1):

There are too many paid and free extension, here are some of the free ones:
http://store.ibnab.com/magento-2-extensions/free-magento-2-easy-megamenu.html
https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-mega-menu-extension.html